# How to stop Rails 3.1 migration from running in a transaction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I want to add an index to a production database. Fortunately we're running Postgres, which nicely allows concurrent indexing, so we can add an index without downtime. The catch -- concurrent indexes cannot be added from within a transaction, and rails migrations wrap everything inside a transaction.

Fortunately, there is something that looks like a really simple solution: overwrite the ActiveRecord::Migration private method ddl_transaction, as [explained here](https://gist.github.com/1081618/9ac3c0a3c0c68b532921cbe823b09685f616738f).

```
class IndexUsersEmails < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def ddl_transaction(&block)
    block.call # do not start a transaction
  end

  def self.up
    execute "CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY index_users_on_email ON users(email)"
  end
end
```

The problem is that it does not seem to work in Rails 3.1. I do exactly what the code in the Gist does, and rails appears to completely ignore it. Any ideas on where to go with this?

Comment: Have you tried changing the method definition so that it's a class method? e.g. `def self.ddl_transaction(&block) ...`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just noticed that I never accepted an answer here, so I should say what I did. Turns out you can get out of the transaction like this:

```
class AddFbPageIdIndexToTabs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute "END"
    execute "CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY bob_lob_law_index ON bob_lob (law)"
    execute "BEGIN"
  end

  def down
    execute "END"
    execute "DROP INDEX CONCURRENTLY bob_lob_law_index"
    execute "BEGIN"
  end
end
```

Just run an `execute "END"` before the thing you want to run outside the transaction. This will end the transaction that ActiveRecord::Migration automagically set up for the migration. After you are done with the code you want to run outside the transaction, `execute "BEGIN"` opens a new transaction so that ActiveRecord::Migration can go through its cleanup process and close the transaction that it thinks it opened.

(I forget where online I found this trick, and can't find it now. Edits welcome to source this!)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying this is the "right way" to do it, but what worked for me was to run just that one migration in isolation.

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20120801151807
```

where 20120801151807 is the timestamp of the CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY migration.

Apparently, it doesn't use a transaction when you run a single migration.